# Convert UTC to local time in map label using an expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, timestamp

I am trying to figure out a way to convert a datetime stamp of the last_edited_date (tracking changes) that is stored in UTC to local time.

I am putting together a map service that allows our heavy equipment folks to update road conditions for our campus during a snow storm.  When users view the map I want to show the last edited date for each feature so people know how long ago a road was plowed.  I want to pull the last_edited_date field and show it in a label.  Unfortunately the time is UTC and the labels do not autoconvert to local browser time when viewing the map service.  Since our heavy equipment folks are updating the map via a feature service, switching to Database time to the track changes in sde wont work.

I am hoping someone knows of some kind of expression to either straight up convert or at least know of someway to subtract 7 hours from the time (we are in the pacific time zone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python and dates? Gotta be [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)!

This worked for me in ArcMap, though I'm not sure how it will be handled on other machines with different date display formats. Should give you a start, I hope.

Label expression treats data as strings (similarly when rounding numeric fields, you need to cast them) so to easily work with dates you need to convert the string to a `datetime` object, subtract your offset, and then convert back to a string.

```py
def FindLabel ([date]):
  import datetime
  fmt = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
  utc = datetime.datetime.strptime([date], fmt)
  offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=7)
  return datetime.datetime.strftime(utc - offset, fmt)
```

Here it is displaying in ArcMap. It's not perfect as you can see since the output is zero-padded.
[image]

Comment: This did the trick, the only hitch was now that we are in daylight savings I had to subtract 8 hours rather than the 7.  Luckily since we are using this for snow removal I shouldn't have to worry about switching it back come spring time, although we have gotten snow as late as June before :) Thank you so much for your help!!!